# PHP : HTTP_request2: saving a file from reponse body from a post request

Tags: php, http-request2

I need help making this to work. My request works fine in postman, i get access to my file (zip file in this example) by clicking the button save response as: in postman. In php, i am trying to access the same file but cant find how. Headers are receiving filename, file size etc. I tried to write getBody() to file but its not my file its just a string.

Here is my function to do the post request:

```
<?php
/**********************************************************************************************/
// Obtention des documents d'un workflow 
// reçoit les params:
// MyworkflowId= l'id du workflow
// MyprefixUrl= url de départ de consigno
// 
// 
// utilise la variable session X-Auth-Token utilisable pour toutes les autres requêtes.
/**********************************************************************************************/
function getDocumentsFromWorkflow($MyprefixUrl,$MyworkflowId)
{

    $request = new HTTP_Request2();
    $request->setUrl($MyprefixUrl.'/workflows/'.$MyworkflowId.'/documents'); 

    $request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
    $request->setConfig(array(
      'follow_redirects' => TRUE,
      'store_body' => TRUE
    ));
    $request->setHeader(array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ));
    //on passe notre variable session token à l'api pour certifier
    //qu'on est authentifié.
    $request->addPostParameter(array(
        'X-Auth-Token' => $_SESSION['consignoToken']

    ));

    try 
    {
        $response = $request->send();
        if ($response->getStatus() == 200) 
        {

            echo "<br> Téléchargement des fichiers du dossier : ". $MyworkflowId;
            echo "<br>". $response->getHeader('content-type')."<br>";
            echo $response->getHeader('content-disposition')."<br>";

            //$myfilename will be treated with substring of Content-Disposition
            //for the sake of testing, i wrote a static name identical to the one received in this header
            $myfilename = "2020-126.zip";
            $filebytes = $response->getHeader('content-length');
            //affichage de la taille du fichier en MB avec seulement 2 décimales. 
            $mysize = number_format($filebytes/1048576,2);
            echo $mysize." mb<br>";
            echo "<pre>";
            $mycontent = $response->getBody();
            //var_dump($mycontent);
            

            //fonctionne ouvre le fichier sur le serveur et enregistre.
            //
            //file_put_contents("uploads/".$myfilename, $mycontent);
            /*foreach ($response->getHeader() as $k => $v) 
            
            {
                    echo "\t{$k}: {$v}<br>";
            }*/

            // tested this to see if file download was triggered but instead of getting my file, 
            //it saves current php page as filename 
            //header('Content-Type: '.$response->getHeader('content-type'));
            //header('Content-disposition: '.$response->getHeader('content-disposition'));
            var_dump($response);

            echo "</pre>";
        }
        else 
        {
                echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' .
                $response->getReasonPhrase();
        }
    }
    catch(HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) 
    {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


}
?>
```

var_dump of response gives:

```
object(HTTP_Request2_Response)#6 (9) {
  ["version":protected]=>
  string(3) "1.1"
  ["code":protected]=>
  int(200)
  ["reasonPhrase":protected]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["effectiveUrl":protected]=>
  string(97) "https://groupetcj.cloud-sandbox1.consigno.com/api/v1/workflows/5f4c3dd954e4f7113c44cfd6/documents"
  ["headers":protected]=>
  array(12) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(29) "Wed, 09 Sep 2020 13:21:49 GMT"
    **["content-type"]=>
    string(15) "application/zip"**
    **["content-length"]=>
    string(6) "702727"**
    ["connection"]=>
    string(10) "keep-alive"
    ["x-auth-token"]=>
    string(1900) "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"
    **["content-disposition"]=>
    string(35) "attachment; filename="2020-126.zip""**
    ["x-content-type-options"]=>
    string(7) "nosniff"
    ["x-xss-protection"]=>
    string(13) "1; mode=block"
    ["cache-control"]=>
    string(46) "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    ["pragma"]=>
    string(8) "no-cache"
    ["expires"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["x-frame-options"]=>
    string(4) "DENY"
  }
  ["cookies":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["lastHeader":protected]=>
  string(15) "x-frame-options"
  ["body":protected]=>
  string(5792) "PK�J)Qscooter exam.pdf��uT۳��{���g�������Np�$Xpw\���A9���;���޺������u����w��]4����,�4�[�3�(�6���5:??���=����b`g��p��`V%;�����Ϊ��x8y����];��| �M_Pbo�[��:��3��K Nt���߆o���؁�c nп00ǿ����¸������%��q����;���� 0ۿ00����O}@;�?�A`���`���>��`/�8�����������q��������  �'?v�?c�B�_��rs������8؀�������/��/���_vy����8y@\��������/����X����V�gt��R}�Ȫ���
`�z�,V{s;��sq]~1��$H���������K�DAb`NA~6���"*!"�%�������A"< NvInq.A}Veg���4d�xI<Wcg�?��
��FBI�9f�O�KZٺB�Y%m�]!�S3��EnVy����%�%#XU�\��.��c;t�5#���}��bT���
��Ac2�}�q���^�Hd�rbւo�://-H$=('>�6~w����觑�zeϓ�g��;[!�^LZ�5َ���M"m����[85���ʠk�u3#,mxPBNP�&q�9ܦ
4T &�{t��B���J����7������1��Gȕ�\�\e�]!��./��*[@䍽�\Y��!b�nv��
�c��Qt����La�c���#�U�E����������!�{��Rܿ��S�����؋i����������U������K��T����*i��?���� 
{7c�!j���s���_�yI7[[USg�^bi�n���_^��"��(:� ��ފ9;8�:x겱�d����|9r��Y���x�o3+��WQe����WU .nο���`�\_� ���������!�=egSU��.�˟��ӕU��EXL�UK��b��"#��lfnhke��01�45��X88:�ۙ�Y�Cl!��v�6�?���,���%��?��� �j� f�
����6����\��쇤�va���[�O&�J�5t�㥷��1Pm�>&�͑���$�)��^)Ҙe���ˡ[�421�6ܾ���5��g�����|(��q����� _�9j��%��������.��k���#�z
[��WB�+.�W��Նv�~�Y��N&��2��C��Vd�beQQb2cj�Я���W2�]�|K�Ua��z�Pf�{).+���r{�@zշ�i-�Fׯ��U��2�w3O}w������(0B�8�m9��=#x���ˈ�,M���O�X-�ɝY��-�x9�O�lp��%}2!:�ٛy��s�!�.��,$�?lTlvb��u;Iܶ�я�{Y^,�Ŀ�9��~P  �9^��-
�kC��+�����S��z�����~BʾZ{�/�[䯺%������]˜��{SCλs�^^�����סo�J��W�`iƯ�z�7��3r��#��ƿ�{�X��V�b���+�R*giM��wV�5��Ds#��`�Ͱ�al`u�CQz�o/
}�\�
ν���4{��0�x,Gc5����+ȕQ䁂���Jt:���~�ȉ�GPou?��C�I��6�gR��NEH�g!>���;el�4mH��a(s�U��e��+ff�Q���TԎpP����n��}�-
�/�L�'��
����t������^�T����2������2s��l��DV��L�$��   zZDIE�޶�r��c?��O�����|E��_O#'���A�hӁ��lޅ�'I ˁ�c)9v�9&���EhPL�h;��Rc+�գTi����L2�w�d���Mܯ�C��G�xc=c�ߨ��mB�%�<ȗ����2rs�Ε��X�+���j�[�V��+�ޞJ��0G�l��/G~���7j��o�9[�"�A!��s�{A�g��Be��q��?��Q�y|���Ut���d�o*���^u�nl���:YUM�]Uo>���M�;��}��YQJ�O!���U�Y��=[�55�{�����<�<�E���Si���D��S�x�a����vsMO�d=�o^�M��7���)^̱��z��]�l�DW4���LZ�>G����'�P�����b>��Vb`m��:�V���2�����΁W�u���8'jW�m���-n2��t�W�����ccd��͢������(��iO�Z�Eb���ܟ���";�����$�A�c�H��/�A�)�v���A7ηw�k�G� �܉���A��:G��I-���(���.vb�J�;�V2u}��Ϙ��y��ZC��^���]}�vv���=YI��[U�;;�g.P������U'�88�3�܏HI&م�b��~Na���  ,%�o���a�8a��y�Z�a�Y�1!1xT��j.�^�1@�ݳ�Ͼ�Aվ���+cdF����^�A3G~q����@v�C��Q���'ҍ��鳑�+m1���En2����X���R���ZyZ0ޯ-h�$�o2�TM��N{�>�J�,��Z�G�R�L�g�%���h��w�!\�!
5�g�-1n��<\���3�-�#�d!e0R��I��5Y�g��De���$�F��J}3��Ɓˎ�r����UKv��,��7�vhUzH�(|�l���p�U�v��Y��M��t>��
^���F��Ӱ���GU5`����\�%z�F��9v����:�S�i���X>��k��,
�M�c�T�X    ��7��<=��x�"?(�襐5�<ő�ү��j��jw�,�
{�j�2���F�����JD�T|李,�@��w�ͫ��2FU+ҌV����ڕ   �R{)�j�z�}å�i���+�u�>����ID�?.-�Y�z��5�ī�1�� �lf�����ح^��}@'[\�[�=f�`�.M���W�s�-5h3�:�&�<��t�9"��8��#!YG7�ĸlM�2��x�C�j�X�Ԣu�l�ZTP�k�?l�>�m��5ӏ���|r�:4���R��np��K�P���B��n
��\κ�đI_���aec*�wߞ�<��^Ҁi������<��/��������w�������!E*�L�jvR����*��]X�g�?�L���TN�,����8!`�����Rb;���#�asRuM�(����C��g�v#h��d�*�l�?��;7�@�ib�}b�)q�̲%;$�����(����W��6����k���#?������(���_��0t��Z�qE�,qY-���z�'�)Uז�'؞1���u�=I��6q�����.�C�1w�k�X���Q�Ӹ�0a��)Uz�n�a�8a����t�H]��
��Tu��=m�d�>�1���j�[9m�q����l�j�KgXǫOI?�~M4�|o�} c)�����4�/�"t��ڛ,��@@�����BK�H�Z��NKKmS�e�Q�<�OKj�lFZ|������9����~u�������g�sZ���lL���H    >K�]�~^�z�]AEThV����g���S�Ó%�c��+�~�h7��G[�����}ƨ����F\���#6,!�����n�:4��Ox3C�k�"zdՊ����q��#m���g��5T�  T�4�=ͩ��z�,�Z�Fᎆ'#��fY_O�07��ՉT��N)��732Fx�eL�B��e�v9q9i���wo6�$X)05�Щ��xK��(���+�,��Y��ra�g��:��ZMu�� �my�U�0֞7�{4��6�U��S*X^��:•�k5F���q���w<}}�5]�y��K���s�;�
��>
7��)�
�V蟛�t����uq���5
��,�I/� �+�a<�^��(?�VBPա/��y    ��g�GUM�G%F(�D�����e*d���Eh$�"�qT
6��9���Ղ�ue��\M�OY�R2bl��ZͲ)�5ߢU-���o���F��g,��Eђr�.>�Sᣛr�^�ɩ����iq��j1�*��}�����KA��t�uW0~;P�5TN��m�O$jh���2�ҏ�
߸�FG�n#���%�R�&�Ej�����T���4��l�u�i�.�L{8t�{���D�;3]���Oth�ҧAwҲt�< Y��y~����{x�(�<�/��Ht'a�h�A9 '"e�H7��S9TR�eB�����ϩ=9�ğ��u�
'�K^���&+r��[�����k�\�@XĿ���uن�Ri�*��̵�dp�gj����A�Ƚ���I�XA�j��D@��J�D��g��nM�   a�=�R�GM�|� A�W��$˕!���?��Ip�j�uڒ̏�n~�|����p�ɱ=�c�**����]��~nh��|b��鞲}R��+����I��7�_@����ʝZ�x�a�'����SR%|c�/s�͏_ms���d:^ˌK7i�$$5/��*n3�\A� �O��K{
9�%�SN��P�⭥�9��g��ϙ�d&U�    �6��z���<��'���܋,/��/|�ψo5�;�P��<�O�m|^���V›-�����&s�÷?\��Q@w��m
gq֛Ɛ�t��]H!���&�
O�])t-fv���hrNFIh���f�W���Ӂ3��������楤f��%���>�t��X�NZ�<��Y*��qx)�&!���=e��+ݡ4�'�9׺TY^KN�B�U�}"�O*�ko,~��@'�P�C���n8ÐBf�v�;�n�/��g�\��Q���Q�Eq�&8�^O�����‹m��`^
��*;�u܏���t�X*��m��7�|��OO���Tr|�sz̮8�i� �
�MT$�G��V�.���?N��K~�,�����|}�Ռ���a}��ZPe�^\D���;~b_�4Q��o��ra��s���s�
���}΄��ƺ��|x�5���v^�Nf��1��sD�"�w-v�dD����4�'
+
����ִ��PV�)No�����_�.v�<f(cduEI�k�(l��]St�
��P���������"�A&�3�O��(�CB��>d{�(.���?t+�zS9g�.=el ,��c�Q'nN}�G��C�ֵU^�!���1=�/��?}.���ޮ3��5c�u�KaV�u����0z�Ƚ�L�Ƈ�-���.�q�b<��S>��A��G9�mϽ�Q0=c�p"��    ي�h�mV�C2�!ף쁧w27���BL����z���~��=�1Z"�"Q�''Y�J�"�Z̢�z%�BB�oO��5р43���H4E,^��^)Ks14  �
�?H�W��h0��p�0�?�H�_�zƘ����Je=�{O��E��4�A,n�~�rݷ�[K2mVR�ms��#]�j����9N("
  ["bodyEncoded":protected]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

Comment: you said it's just a string when you wrote it to a file, what code did you use? I still think the body is binary

Comment: i used //file_put_contents("uploads/".$myfilename, $mycontent); $mycontent being the request->getbody(); I also tried fopen(). what do you suggest?

Comment: what about https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php example #2

Comment: its not that also. problem seems to be receiving an incomplete binary string to create the file. thus giving me an incomplete file to write. I noticed that var_dump(request->getBody()); is giving me a different size... and output for the same file i should be receiving. I went into my php.ini file to adjust output_buffering and post_max_size but didnt change anything... still in the dark!

Comment: SOLUTION FOUND: the problem wasn't in my code. Problem seems to be in pear package http_request2. Method getBody() seems to have trouble handling binary files sent in POST body. I tried the same function but using GuzzleHttp package instead and bam, got my file without any problem. If it helps anyone else saving time: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/ . Dont use pear package :)